# Encrypting like BitLocker

Tags: windows, encryption

Is it possible to encrypt like bitlocker? I've been playing with a lot of other disk encryption software but requires a password after BIOS.

As a remote support company, we need to be able to reboot encrypted machines but can't always expect someone to be there to enter a password.

So the real question is, can software work like BitLocker where files are decrypted onbootup using the users password or because this is built into Windows only Windows has this ability?

EDIT:
Not asking for software. Basically, asking is the ability how BitLocker works only able to work(decrypting by logging in as said user) because it is concept built in Windows or can other software do the same thing.

Comment: Are you asking if there are third-party alternatives to Bitlocker?

Comment: If it gets decrypted by logging in you are either not using bitlocker or it is not working like you think it is. Either you are using EFS (Encrypting File System, which is not BitLocker) or you are using Bitlocker with a TPM chip and if so the drive is already decrypted by the time you get to the login screen.

Comment: Bitlocker uses (128-bit or 256-bit) AES keys in Cipher Block Chaining (CBC) or XTC mode.  VeraCrypt also supports that.  VeraCrypt cannot decrypt a drive encrypted by Bitlocker at this time.  Can third-party software be written to do so, I don't the reason it could not, but the majority of Bitlocker's feature set is unique to it currently

Comment: It seems like the "encryption at boot" and the "automatic boot" are mutually exclusive ideas... unless there's some remote network unlock or login...?

Comment: "by logging in as said user"  - You can mount a disk encrypted, by Bitlocker, using any user on any machine.  Any software could do the samething, it just does not exist, not enough demand for it.

Comment: _we need to be able to reboot encrypted machines but can't always expect someone to be there to enter a password_ what is the point in encrypting anything if I can just steal the disks, and have it decrypt itself on boot?

Answer (score 0):

You can set up unattended decryption on startup using a BitLocker startup key or a TPM (or both). The later requires hardware integrated in to the motherboard See [this Microsoft article](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-vista/what-is-a-bitlocker-drive-encryption-startup-key-or-pin) for more information.

Comment: Link-only answers are less then helpful.  This also does not seem to answer the author's question.